# easy_install'ing under different Python version

Tags: linux, installation, python, gentoo, easy-install

I'm trying to `easy_install` a Python 2.5 package, but I've also got Python 3.1 installed, so I get a syntax error:

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:                                    
                                    ^                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I tell `easy_install` I want it to install ([ReviewBoard](http://www.review-board.org/), in this case) with Python 2.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `easy_install` code installs the packages for whichever version of Python is being used to run it.  It sounds like your system default version of Python is 3.1, so something like this should make it work the way you want:

`/path/to/python2.5 /path/to/easy_install ReviewBoard`

Worst case you can edit the `easy_install` script and change the shebang to point to your 2.5 binary.

Comment: Weirdly enough, there are scripts for `easy_install-2.6` and `easy_install-3.1`, but none for 2.5, although it's installed (Gentoo). Only changing the shebang didn't work, because there's a `from pkg_resources import load_entry_point` and it gives me an `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`. The script uses distribute-0.6.4 (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), but I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: I believe Distribute is backwards compatible, so what I think you're missing is setuptools for your 2.5 install.  Alternatively, you could install Distribute for 2.5.  Basically follow the directions here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions but use "python2.5" wherever it calls for "python".

Comment: Assuming your Python 2.5 binary is called "python2.5", of course.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.6 recently became stable on Gentoo, and it looks like it's installed as you're having an easy_install-2.6 script - so it might be that some things got mixed up. That's what I'd do:

In case you're willing to update to python-2.6 (at some point you'll have to):

- install python 2.6
- use `eselect python` to select the right version
- run python-updater something alike: `python-updater -o 2.5 -- -av`

In case you want to stay with 2.5:

Try to clean up your installation:

- Use `eselect python` to make sure 2.5 is selected
- Re-merge `dev-python/setuptools`
- Eventually run `revdep-rebuild -- -a` to clean things up