# Easy_install/setuptools is installing libraries to my Python 2.4 directory instead of my Python 2.6 directory

Tags: centos, python, easy-install, setuptools

How do I make setup tools install libraries to the python 2.6 directory?

I am in Centos.

Easy_install/setuptools is installing libraries to my Python 2.4 directory instead of my Python 2.6 directory (After I upgraded from 2.4 to 2.6).  How do I make setup tools install libraries to the python 2.6 directory?

I had to upgrade to 2.6 to use WSGI module to run Django with Apache....

Answer (score 1):

For more details about easy_install support with multiple versions of Python check out [Multiple-Python-Versions](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#multiple-python-versions) found at packages.python.org.

> As of version 0.6a11, EasyInstall
>   installs itself under two names:
>   easy_install and easy_install-N.N,
>   where N.N is the Python version used
>   to install it. Thus, if you install
>   EasyInstall for both Python 2.3 and
>   2.4, you can use the easy_install-2.3 or easy_install-2.4 scripts to install
>   packages for Python 2.3 or 2.4,
>   respectively.
>
> Also, if you’re working with Python
>   version 2.4 or higher, you can run
>   Python with -m easy_install to run
>   that particular Python version’s
>   easy_install command.

Basically, easy_install and setuptools install libraries to the version of Python that is being used to run them.  So it sounds like 2.4 is the version of Python being used when easy_install/setuptools is run.  See the following question/answer on ServerFault: [easy_install'ing under different Python version](https://serverfault.com/questions/73741/easy-installing-under-different-python-version)

It's possible that you could setup (or modify) a symlink for `/usr/bin/python` to point to the python install (2.6 I would assume) that you would like to use by default.